# std::bad_alloc when I forgot to increment the iterator

Tags: c++, bad-alloc

I have two questions about the following piece of code. First, I initially forgot to increment the loop and as a result I got `std::bad_alloc` when I ran the code. After debugging I couldn't quite understand why the mistake leads that error.

My second question is if there exist a more efficient way to store the of the objects of the type `pcl::PointXYZ` than a vector? Can I avoid copying them?

```
#include <unordered_set>
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

// Sample without replacement over a range using Bob Floyd's algorithm
std::unordered_set<int> sampleWithoutReplacement(int sampleSize, int rangeUpperBound)
{
    std::unordered_set<int> sample;
    std::default_random_engine generator;

    for(int d = rangeUpperBound - sampleSize; d < rangeUpperBound; d++)
    {
        int t = std::uniform_int_distribution<>(0, d)(generator);
        if (sample.find(t) == sample.end() )
            sample.insert(t);
        else
            sample.insert(d);
    }
    return sample;
}

unsigned maxIterations {100};
while(maxIterations--) 
{
        std::unordered_set<int> inliers;
        std::unordered_set<int> sampleIndices = sampleWithoutReplacement(sampleSize, cloudSize);
        std::vector<pcl::PointXYZ> samplePoints {};
        for  (auto it { sampleIndices.begin() }; it != sampleIndices.end(); ++it)
        {
            samplePoints.push_back(cloud->points.at(*it));
        }
// some other code that uses samplePoints. 

}
```

Comment: [Mre] please.  Remove the irrelevant things and add the minimal code needed to compile.

Answer (score 1):

As for your first question, you can look at [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/bad_alloc) and see that std::bad_alloc is thrown when there is a failure to allocate. In essence, you've run out of memory by continuously pushing to a vector.

As for total memory overhead, you won't really see a noticeable difference on modern systems. If we're being technical, and you know the exact size of how many elements you want to store, an array would be more efficient on memory. If you're concerned about how long it takes to find an element, std::map is faster than std::vector(O(logn) for std::map and O(n) for std::vector).